AlmaLinux vault repository
When and how to use the vault repository referenced here, especially the link at the bottom that points to the vault folder.
I have tried the following:
   17  sudo dnf install vault
   18  sudo dnf install vault.almalinux
   19  sudo dnf install almalinux-vault
   20  sudo dnf install vault
   21  sudo dnf install almalinux-release-vault

My true goal is that I need some i686 static libraries and shared libraries for some C programs, and they might be in that repository someplace, according to the note at the bottom of the first link.

I've also been looking into pulling stuff from the Vault repo and haven't been able to find any reference on how to do it 'cleanly'... You can always add the repository manually under /etc/yum.repos.d with something like:
$ cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-vault.repo <<EOF
[appstream-vault]
name=AlmaLinux Vault 9.4 - AppStream
# mirrorlist=https://mirrors.almalinux.org/mirrorlist/$releasever/appstream
baseurl=https://repo.almalinux.org/vault/9.4/AppStream/$basearch/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
countme=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-AlmaLinux-9
metadata_expire=86400
enabled_metadata=1
EOF

Please note how I manually baked in the AlmaLinux version I'm using (i.e. 9.4). If you manually navigate to https://repo.almalinux.org/vault/9/AppStream/x86_64/, which is what you would get if leveraging the usual $releasever in the repo's definition, you'll see it's completely empty!
At any rate, let me know if this works out for you. Best of luck!

I use this script:
>generate-almalinux-vault-repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-vault.repo >/dev/null

It automatically generates AlmaLinux vault repos for all previous versions of BaseOS, AppStream, and CRB. They are disabled by default, as they should be. Enable them using:
>sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled baseos-9.4

etc.
